# how to play video URL with https connection with improper certificate, when video is played in embedded html

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have a UIWebView where we are playing video's using embedded html and opening the webview using **loadHtmlString**.

But if the video URL is a HTTPS with improper certificate, we were not able to load the video.

For **normal webpage** URL with HTTPS and improper certificate, if we override the NSURLConnection it **works**... But it is **not working for videos** opened using **loadHtmlString**

Any Clues on how to open a video using **loadHtmlString**, when URL has HTTPS with improper certificate....

Thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 0):

Derive a class from NSURLProtocol and register it in your app delegate.

This will enable you to intercept the https request and substitute it with your own request using NSURLConnection, then within the NSURLConnection's willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge: you can ignore the improper certificate, and when you have the results back you can forward them to the UIWebView via the NSURLProtocol.

This is going to be a bit tricky dealing with situations such as connectivity disappearing half way through the loading of the web page, a non responding server, keeping things asynchronous etc.